# Run multiple subqueries(correlated) for the two separate operations from different tables and joining into one table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, aggregate-functions

I am trying to utilise two subqueries but could not find the right way, the below query of mine is not the correct way to do it. Please help me know how I can use the subqueries of creating column `revenue` and `spend`. one subquery works but how to include both. Also can the same logic be derived through `joins` with less execution time?

```
select country, location, postalcode, MAX(spend), MAX(revenue)
from (select a.*,
             (select SUM(r.revenue)
              from return r
              where r.uid = a.uid and
               r.dt >= a.dt - interval 10 minute and
               r.dt <= a.dt + interval 10 minute and
               r.cat_id in ('1200') and
               
             ) as revenue
             (select SUM(spend)
             from invest a
             where r.uid = a.uid and
              a.category = '433'
              a.cat_id in ('0', '1200') and
              a.event in ('begin')
             ) as spend
      from invest a
      where a.event in ('show1', 'show2', 'begin') and 
            a.category = '433' and
            
     ) a
group by country, location, postalcode
```

Also can the same logic be derived through `joins` with less execution time?

```
**Invest Table**
dt                  user cat_id cat location  postal     event    spent
2020-11-01 22:12:25  1     0    A      US      X12        Show      2
2020-11-01 22:12:25  1     0    A      US      X12        Show      2 (duplicate also in table)
2020-11-01 22:12:25  1     6    A      US      X12        Mid      null
2020-11-01 22:13:20  2     0    B      UK      L23        Show      2
2020-11-01 22:15:24  2     3    B      UK      L23        End      null
```

```
**Revenue table**
dt                     user  cat_id   revenue
2020-11-01 22:14:45     1      6        null
2020-11-01 22:13:20     2      3        3
```

Want to create final table(by aggregating on revenue for each 'postal' area):

```
location   postal   spend  revenue returns
UK          X12      2       0        0
US          L23      2       3        3/2=1.5
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

One of the sub-queries (spend) can be removed at all:

```
select country, location, postalcode,
             SUM(case when a.event= 'begin' and a.cat_id in ('0', '1200') then spend end) as spend,
             (select SUM(r.revenue)
              from return r
              where r.uid = a.uid and
               r.dt >= a.dt - interval 10 minute and
               r.dt <= a.dt + interval 10 minute and
               r.pixel_id in ('1200') and -------------why is this and ?
               
             ) as revenue
      from invest a
      where a.event in ('show1', 'show2', 'begin') and 
            a.category = '433' 
            
group by country, location, postalcode
```

Second subquery can be joined:

```
select country, location, postalcode,
             SUM(case when a.event= 'begin' and a.cat_id in ('0', '1200') then spend end) as spend,
             b.revenue
      from invest a 
           left join                  
         (select SUM(r.revenue) revenue, dt, uid
              from return r
              where
               r.pixel_id in ('1200')
               group by dt
               
             ) b ON b.uid = a.uid and
                    b.dt >= a.dt - interval 10 minute and
                    b.dt <= a.dt + interval 10 minute 
      where a.event in ('show1', 'show2', 'begin') and 
            a.category = '433' 
            
group by country, location, postalcode, b.revenue
```

Comment: I tried by the logic as suggested by you it seems there is syntax issue at the ```return r``` part. Please see this ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'return r where r.uid = a.uid and r.dt >= a.dt - interval 10 minu' at line 16```. Issue seems to be in the ```FROM return r``` part

Comment: @SachinKumar Sure it contains `and ` in the WHERE without condition, like in your original query. Remove it or write some boolean expression

Comment: @SachinKumar Only you can debug it, unfortunately I cannot reproduce because have no your tables and data

Comment: thank you, I have updated the question with tables. doing joins on uid but when the condition on "where" clause comes  like ```where r.uid = a.uid``` then there is constant pop up of the error ```cannot resolve '`a.`' given input columns: [r.dt, r.referer, r.revenue, r.stamp]``` which means it is looking into just one table columns that is ```r```. Is it something because of the error in joining operation if you can suggest

Comment: @SachinKumar Oh yes. the bug is obviously here :  r.dt >= a.dt - interval 10 minute and
               r.dt <= a.dt + interval 10 minute and      ----it references table a and it should not, because You said it is NOT corellated.

Comment: @SachinKumar And if you need correllated join, then use LEFT instead of cross and use this condition r.dt >= a.dt - interval 10 minute and
               r.dt <= a.dt + interval 10 minute and as join ON condition

Comment: @SachinKumar Please read my update. Also check the join does not duplicates. Maybe you need some additional join condition.

Comment: Yes additional joins would be needed. I was trying to solve it using multiple subqueries but couldn't include those two as asked in my question. So thought and asked if joins can be better option than subquery and how to make those subqueries work together, some way or the other even joins are faulting so no all joins are working in sync

Comment: @SachinKumar Anyway most probably you can remove self join. Correlated inline join I guess performs the same as usual join. Check the plan and you will see

Comment: True that. As you suggested even after left join the issue persists ```cannot resolve '`a.uid`' given input columns: [r.dt, r.referer, r.revenue, r.stamp]```

Comment: @SachinKumar move that also to the ON condition: `ON r.uid = a.uid and
                    r.dt >= a.dt - interval 10 minute and
                    r.dt <= a.dt + interval 10 minute `

Comment: But in that case then it will throw up the same error on  'a' table. I ran the error is as expected ``` cannot resolve  r.uid given input columns: [a.dt, a.position,a.event,a.spend...]```

Comment: @SachinKumar fixed again. You can do all that yourself alone much faster than asking questions here because it is easier to debug when you have all tables and data? etc

Comment: Yes have to see an alternate way. I found your way of doing very insightful thank you for that

Comment: @SachinKumar You are welcome